# uncaught exception in webIDE when running firefox os simulator

Tags: ember.js, firefox-os

I was running ffos 2.0 simulator in webIDE and testing world-clock example as given in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Modern_web_app_architecture on windows 7 machine. This throws uncaught exception [object object]   line no: unknown and white screen in simulator. In firefox browser 36, it runs fine without reporting any error in firebug.

I scaled down the world-clock example to the point, where there is no clock or timnezone page. It is just http://localhost:4200/. Even this is working in ff browser but throwing same error in webIDE console. In debugger of webIDE, on choosing pause on exception, it pauses at div.queryselectorall("*,:x").

Somebody, please help!

Comment: It's worth trying WebIDE in Firefox Nightly to see if maybe a bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. 
To resolve it : in `/config/environment.js` ,

```
if (environment === 'development') {
       ENV.locationType = 'hash';
}
```

Do the same for 'production' to use as packaged app.